# What does this regex do?

Tags: regex

```
(?!magazine/.*$)(.*)\.php
```

It was being used to crawl a website.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regular expression matches anything that is followed by `.php` (`(.*)\.php`) and that does not begin with `magazine/` (`(?!magazine/.*$)`).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all php documents rooted at magazine.